# mariadb 10.3.7 gcache page files not deleted

Tags: mysql, mariadb

env:

3 node ubuntu

cluster : galera cluster

**but it is not deleting any of those files.**

2018-07-31 22:52:28 16 [Note]  
The slave is applying a ROW event on behalf of an UPDATE statement on table tbl_citation and is currently taking a considerable amount of time (15160 seconds). 
 This is due to the fact that it is scanning an index while looking up records to be processed. 
 Consider adding a primary key (or unique key) to the table to improve performance. 
2018-08-01 10:28:47 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000024 of size 223519200 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:31:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000025 of size 213830368 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:41:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000026 of size 148633736 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:47:13 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000027 of size 139333384 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:51:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000028 of size 1083412888 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:53:14 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000029 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:55:52 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000030 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:56:02 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000031 of size 149653616 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:56:18 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000032 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:56:29 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000033 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:56:41 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000034 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 10:56:57 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000035 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:04:00 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000036 of size 1096513816 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:11:02 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000037 of size 1320254568 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:19:09 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000038 of size 1298663000 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:25:12 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000039 of size 1393501816 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:31:07 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000040 of size 1192945600 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:36:35 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000041 of size 1232606760 bytes 
2018-08-01 11:41:52 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000042 of size 1041832800 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:20:52 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000043 of size 1101323016 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:37:55 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000044 of size 422462808 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:47:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000045 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:49:21 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000046 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:53:29 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000047 of size 134217728 bytes 
2018-08-01 12:58:43 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000048 of size 365713696 bytes 
2018-08-01 13:03:32 0 [Note] WSREP: Created page /mnt/s01/mariadb_data/gcache.page.000049 of size 134217728 bytes

Comment: I have same issue with `10.3.13-MariaDB` not sure what is the solution